# Excel VBA Speed Up Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen similar questions asked but I haven't been successful in tweaking the answers to solve what I'm trying to do. I have some code in VBA which looks through a range and fills in some formulas. The problem is it takes hours to run. I think the fact that it iterates over each cell instead of a range or array is part of the problem. I'm just not sure how to re-write it to be faster since I'm a newbie with VBA (I can piece together code I find and get it to work but I'm not at the level where I can just write it on my own). Someone I was friendly with at my company helped me with the initial code and they are no longer here. There's only about 50 rows of data and 30 columns. I know having the VBA insert formulas into cells can be a bit slower but I need it to be formulas and not values. Here's what the code looks like:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


Set sh = Sheet9

Row = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Col = sh.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  
 For i = 700 To Row
    For c = 32 To Col
        If sh.Cells(5, c).Text <> "" Then
        periods = sh.Range("Z" & i).Value
        
        If sh.Cells(5, c).Text = sh.Range("X" & i).Text Then
            If IsEmpty(sh.Cells(i, c)) Then
            sh.Cells(i, c).Formula = "=$AB" & i
            c2 = c
            Do While c2 <= Col
                c2 = c2 + periods / 3 * 2
                 If c2 <= Col Then
                    sh.Cells(i, c2).Formula = "=$AB" & i
                End If
            Loop
        End If
        End If
        
        If sh.Cells(5, c).Text = sh.Range("Y" & i).Text Then
            If IsEmpty(sh.Cells(i, c + 1)) Then
            sh.Cells(i, c + 1).Formula = "=$AA" & i & "/" & 4 & "*" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Days(sh.Cells(4, c + 1), sh.Range("$W" & i)) & "/" & 90
            c2 = c + 1
            Do While c2 <= Col
                c2 = c2 + periods / 3 * 2
                If c2 <= Col Then
                    sh.Cells(i, c2).Formula = "=$AA" & i & "/" & 4
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End If
End If
Next c
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why include Application.WorksheetFunction to generate something that could be part of the formula? Also, if your code works but you just want ot optimize it, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask

Comment: Every time you read a cell that costs you performance-wise, so you should try not to read the same cell multiple times: eg. you access `sh.Cells(5, c)` 3 times for each iteration.  Just read that once into a variable and then use the variable.

Comment: Likewise you read `sh.Range("X" & i)` multiple times inside the inner `c` loop - you should read that (and the Col Y/Z values) into a variable once before entering the inner loop.

Comment: in addition to the rest, If the data amount is very large, - simple formulas may cause performance issues...
Do you really need to insert formulas into cells, - maybe the value will be enough?